# Problems with a query in MySql (LIKE between two table columns)

Tags: mysql

i have the following sql sentence:

```
    SELECT a.id_payment, a.id_adjustment, a.line, b.amount, a.name, a.id_user, c.name, a.amount_before_discount, a.percentage_discount, a.amount_discount, b.date, b.sucursal 
FROM es_payment a, es_payments_successful b, es_payment_adjustment c 
WHERE a.line LIKE 'b.line%' 
AND a.id_adjustment = c.id_adjustment 
AND ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(b.date) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-09-01')) 
AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(b.date) <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-09-12'))) 
GROUP BY a.id_payment
```

The problem is that i want to compare the a.line column with the b.line column but it compares with the value as the string "b.line", not the value of this column, could you please help me?

Answer (score 6):

```
WHERE a.line LIKE CONCAT(b.line, '%')
```

Answer (score 1):

WHERE a.line LIKE '%' || b.line || '%'